# How to log Webservice events in IIS with EVENT/ERROR Mechanism

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I am building a webservice for a customer. I have built the webservice but the customer wants me to log all event/error message to a text file under IIS Event/Error mechanism. Can anyone tell me what this means? I was basically logging each transaction to the database table, and he didnt like it. Can I log IIS status within my webservice application?

I have no idea what he means by logging with IIS Event/Error Mechanism. Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably means event log.

Comment: but IIS already does it itself. What else am I supposed to do, right?

Comment: Clarify it maybe they mean event logs